# caption placement and reference

Tags: longtable

I am having a trouble with caption and reference of longtable

```
\documentclass[stu,12pt]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\title{title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Winter is cold in \ref{column_table}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.4cm} | p{5cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{2.3cm}}
\caption{Seasons of Island A}
\label{column_table}
\endfirsthead
\endhead
\hline
  & Season   & Temp  & Length   & Popular \\ \hline
1 & Spring   & Warm  & Nominal  & Yes  \\ \hline
2 & Summer   & Hot   & Nominal  & Yes  \\ \hline
3 & Winter   & Cold  & Nominal  & Yes  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This generates
[image]

Can I format the table caption to display both the table number and title on the same line, like "Table 1 Seasons of Island A"? Also, is it possible to refer to the table by its name, such as "Winter is cold in Table 1," instead of just using the number?

Comment: This is default  caption style in the `apa7` document class. Why you like change it?

Comment: @Zarko Thank you so much. I just thought it was better.   I wasn't aware that the formatting was already in APA style. Thank you again.

Comment: Note that `center` does not do anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is use tables `longtblr` or `talltblr` of `tabularray` packages. In this case caption formatting are defined by `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[stu,12pt]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{tabularray} % <--- instead of longtable

\title{title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Winter is cold in \ref{long_table} and \ref{tall_table} \dots

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Seasons of Island A},
  label = {long_table}
                ]
                {hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {l  Q[l, wd=5cm] *{3}{Q[l, wd=2.5cm]}},
                 rowhead = 1
                }
%   table body
  & Season   & Temp  & Length   & Popular   \\  
1 & Spring   & Warm  & Nominal  & Yes       \\ 
2 & Summer   & Hot   & Nominal  & Yes       \\ 
3 & Winter   & Cold  & Nominal  & Yes       \\ 
\end{longtblr}


    \begin{center}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Seasons of Island A},
  label = {tall_table}
                ]
                {hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {l  X[l] *{3}{Q[l, wd=2.5cm]}}
                }
%   table body
  & Season   & Temp  & Length   & Popular   \\
1 & Spring   & Warm  & Nominal  & Yes       \\
2 & Summer   & Hot   & Nominal  & Yes       \\
3 & Winter   & Cold  & Nominal  & Yes       \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Seasons of Island A, but this time the caption test is so long that it is broken into two lines},
  label = {tall_table}
                ]
                {hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {l  X[l] *{3}{Q[l, wd=2.5cm]}}
                }
%   table body
  & Season   & Temp  & Length   & Popular   \\
1 & Spring   & Warm  & Nominal  & Yes       \\
2 & Summer   & Hot   & Nominal  & Yes       \\
3 & Winter   & Cold  & Nominal  & Yes       \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{center}
```

and with preserved APA7 caption formatting:

```
    \begin{center}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Seasons of Island A, but this time the caption test is so long that it is break into two lines},
  label = {tblr_table}
                ]
                {hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {l  X[l] *{3}{Q[l, wd=2.5cm]}}
                }
%   table body
  & Season   & Temp  & Length   & Popular   \\
1 & Spring   & Warm  & Nominal  & Yes       \\
2 & Summer   & Hot   & Nominal  & Yes       \\
3 & Winter   & Cold  & Nominal  & Yes       \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{center}
but when you like to preserve original APA7 caption formatting at short tables, you should use `tblr` inserted in `center` environment:
    \begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Seasons of Island A}
  \label{tblr_table}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {l  X[l] *{3}{Q[l, wd=2.5cm]}}
            }
%   table body
  & Season   & Temp  & Length   & Popular   \\
1 & Spring   & Warm  & Nominal  & Yes       \\
2 & Summer   & Hot   & Nominal  & Yes       \\
3 & Winter   & Cold  & Nominal  & Yes       \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This caption formatting is defined in the document class. You should probably  keep it as is because it conforms with the APA formatting (see [APA7 tables](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/tables-figures)).

If you really want to change it and keep using the document class, put the following snippet in your preamble. This requires package [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) but it seems `apa7` already loads it.

```latex
% \usepackage{caption}
\clearcaptionsetup{table}
\captionsetup[table]{
  format=hang,
  justification=centering,
  singlelinecheck,
  labelfont=bf,
  labelsep=period,
}
```